# Prove that the group of $3\times3$ rational unipotent triangular matrices modulo its center is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb Q^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Let $G$ be the group of matrices of the form:

$$\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & a & b \\
    0 & 1 & c \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$

with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Note that the center, $Z(G)$, is the set of matrices where the only nontrivial entry is the upper right corner.

Also note that $Z(G)$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Q}$. Just by map the upper right hand corner to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Show $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

I am having difficulties deriving a map. Any ideas?

Comment: Try projecting from $G$ to the $a$ and $c$ coordinates.

Comment: Questions regarding homework assignments are more than welcome, provided that they: Briefly explain the problem you are trying to solve—do not post your entire assignment verbatim. Explain what you tried and where you're stuck (**showing your work is a good idea**). Don't ask for complete solutions to the problem—we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: This is a review. Completely optional, no grade. I am asking for a hint regarding the map. I have already proved that $G$ is a group and that $Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. $\textbf{Again, I asked for a hint regarding the map}$. Not a proof to the map. I posted the background information as without it, the problem wouldn't make sense. Thanks for being such an awesome guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at the mapping from $G$ to the coordinates $(a,c)$. Then apply one of the isomorphisms theorems.